# Instalation of Windows XP Embeded - How accept EULA

Tags: windows, windows-xp, embedded, installation

I try install Windos XP Embeded with SP 2on my notebook with Windows 7. I have 2 iso files:

- en_winxp_embedded_sp2_cd1.iso ->CD1
- en_winxp_embedded_sp2_cd2.iso ->CD2

I burn this files on CD’s.

I boot notebook from CD, I don’t how can I accept EULA, because I see only commad line.

I type notepad eula.txt, read eula but I don’t how can I accept EULA, because I don’t see any instalation WIZARD.

See this image:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the text says *"By continuing to use this software..."*; if you do not agree, you must stop using it, simple as that.

This is not really a programming question, and is probably a question for Microsoft Support or your Law Department.

It looks like this message is being emitted by WindowesPE (Preinstallation Environment), so you have not yet used or installed the licensed software.  You accept the EULA exactly by installing the software.

Windows Embedded does not install like Desktop Windows, and I'd question the wisdom f installing it on a Laptop.  You have to use Windows Embedded Studio's Target Designer to define a configuration and create a runtime image for your application and hardware platform and then install that.  You do not install XP Embedded on your development PC (except possibly as a dual-boot or virtual machine).